# HTML5 validation not showing when using inputmask for Mobile Number

Tags: jquery, html, validation, jquery-inputmask, input-mask

I have arise one issue When Use input type = "text" with required = "required" for mobile number and Use input mask , at that time if User not enter any value then it not showing html5 validation message But it just Focusing on that text  box but not show validation message Like: Please fill out this field.

Below is my Html and Js Code:

HTMl Code:

---

```
<input type="text" id="s5a77f4f2cd315_phoneNumber" name="s5a77f4f2cd315[phoneNumber]" required="required" class="form-control  phone min form-control" data-placeholder="Phone" maskpattern="(999) 999-9999" minlength="8">
```

Js Code:

---

$(".phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");

What I will do for show validation message?

Answer (score -1):

Why don’t you try to add this code below:

```
Title=“(999) 999-9999”
```

Your validation message will show “please enter as: (999) 999-9999”